# How can I show the expression of "Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, 1, 1 + n, 1 - p]"?

Tags: output-formatting

My formula is

```
f3 = Integrate[(x*p/(1 - x (1 - p)))^(n - 1), {x, 0, 1}, 
      Assumptions -> 0 < p < 1 && n > 1]
```

and it gave me

```
p Gamma[n] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, 2, 1 + n, 1 - p]
```

How can I get the explicit expression?

Comment: What do you mean by "explicit expression"?  Is this not explicit enough?

Comment: How can I get the expression of n and p instead of Gamma[n] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, 2, 1 + n, 1 - p]? I mean, the expression of Gamma function and Hypergeometric2F1Regularized, I don't know what Hypergeometric2F1Regularized is and how to expand.

Comment: If you apply `FunctionExpand`, it will write these in terms of `Hypergeometric2F1`'s.  What is it that you want to *do* with this expression? `Hypergeometric2F1Regularized` is a perfectly acceptable special function, and it's quite possible that it can't be written in terms of more elementary functions. If you can tell us what you actually want to *do* with this function, that might help us answer your question.

Comment: By the way, if you plug in explicit values of $n$ (assuming that $n$ is an integer), it will evaluate to an expression involving a powers of `p` and `Log[p]`.

Comment: Is this clearer? $f_3=\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} \frac{p (1-p)^q}{\binom{n+q}{n-1}}$ (that's what the hypergeometric function means)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a [Lerch transcendent](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi/) would be more explicit for you than a hypergeometric function?

$$
f_3=1-\frac{n-1}p \Phi \left(-\frac{1-p}{p},1,n\right)
$$

This transcendent is defined from $z^n \Phi(z,1,n)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{z^k}{k}=-\ln(1-z)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{z^k}{k}$, and maybe you'll find it useful.

```
f3 = Integrate[(x*p/(1 - x (1 - p)))^(n - 1), {x, 0, 1},
               Assumptions -> 0 < p < 1 && n > 1]
(*    p Gamma[n] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, 2, 1 + n, 1 - p]    *)

Table[f3 == 1 - (n - 1)/p LerchPhi[-(1 - p)/p, 1, n], {n, 12}] // FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> 0 < p < 1] &
(*    {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}    *)
```